# Ajax storing old request

Tags: javascript

I have this function that passes an int type in my ajax, it is selected when clicking the search inventory button, each inventory corresponds to an integer, but if I search for a device first, and then close the modal, and go to search notebooks for example, it keeps making the search request as if it were a device

```
function pesquisarInventario(tipo) {
  $('#modal-buscar-inventario').modal({
    backdrop: "static",
    keyboard: false
  });

  $('#modal-buscar-inventario').modal("show");

  $('input[name="search-pesquisar-inventario"]').on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $(this).trigger("focusout");
    }
  });
  $('#modal-buscar-inventario').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('input[name="search-pesquisar-inventario"]').bind("blur keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.type == "blur" || e.which == 13) {
        var search = $(this).val();
        if (search.length > 3) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              search: search
            },
            url: "/inventario/ajax/pesquisar/inventario/" + tipo,
            beforeSend: function() {
              $("#modal-buscar-inventario table tbody").html('<tr><td colspan="5"><div class="alert alert-info" style="margin-top: 10px"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Pesquisando...</div></td></tr>');
            },
            complete: function() {

            },
            success: function(data) {

              if (data.length > 0) {

                var html = [];
                $(data).each(function(index, inventario) {

                  var serial = (inventario.serial) ? (inventario.serial) : "";
                  var cor = (inventario.cor) ? (inventario.cor).toUpperCase() : "";
                  var marca = (inventario.marca) ? (inventario.marca) : "";
                  var modelo = (inventario.modelo) ? (inventario.modelo) : "";
                  var categoria = (inventario.categoria) ? (inventario.categoria) : "";


                  html.push("<tr data-tipo='" + tipo + "' data-serial='" + serial + "' data-cor='" + cor + "' data-marca='" + marca + "' data-modelo='" + modelo + "' data-categoria='" + categoria + "' data-id='" + inventario.id + "'>");

                  html.push("<td>" + (inventario.serial).toUpperCase() + "</td>");
                  html.push("<td>" + marca.toUpperCase() + "</td>");
                  html.push("<td>" + modelo.toUpperCase() + "</td>");
                  html.push("<td>" + cor.toUpperCase() + "</td>");
                  html.push("<td>" + categoria + "</td>");
                  html.push("<td><button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' type='button' onclick='selecionarInventario(" + inventario.id + ")'><i class='fa fa-hand-o-up' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></td>");

                  html.push("</tr>");
                });

                $("#modal-buscar-inventario table tbody").html(html.join(""));
              } else {
                var html = '<tr><td colspan="7"><div class="alert alert-warning" style="margin-top: 10px"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangule"></i> Nenhum resultado encontrado com o filtro aplicado.</div></td></tr>';
                $("#modal-buscar-inventario table tbody").html(html);
              }
            },
            error: function() {}
          });
        }
      }
    });

  });

  $('#modal-buscar-inventario').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { // do something...
    var html = '<tr><td colspan="5"><div class="alert alert-info" style="margin-top: 10px"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Utilize o campo acima para buscar o responsável.</div></td></tr>';
    $("#modal-buscar-inventario table tbody").html(html);
    $('input[name="search-pesquisar-responsavel"]').val("");
  });

}
```

I tried everything and I don't know if there is a way to delete the cache

Comment: Don't bind an event listener inside another event listener. Every time you show the modal you'll add another lisstener to the input, and it will run multiple times.

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: Where are you passing an integer in the AJAX? `search` looks like it's a search string.

Comment: Are you talking about `tipo`? Every time you call `pesquisarInventario()` you'll add another event listener that uses that value. But you never remove a previous event listener. So all the listeners will be called with different values of `tipo`.

Comment: so, how can i remove de previous event listener? @Barmar

Comment: `$("whatever").off("blur keypress").on("blurr keypress", ...)`

Comment: Or just bind the event listener once, not every time they open the modal. Put `tipo` in a global variable that the listener uses.